# How to resize table width based on screen size

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on this page which contains a table inside modal-body.

The screen i work on is 22 inch and the table looks perfect on that. But when I see it on my laptop Macbook 13 inch, the table extends to the width of the screen.  How do I resize automatically ?
[image]

```
<div class="modal-body"
    style="width: 1600px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;">
    <loading></loading>
    <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}"
        spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default"
            data-ng-repeat="(spec,value) in audit | orderBy: 'specification' | groupBy: 'specification' ">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <b> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                        href="#{{$index+1}}-{{value.id}}" target="_self"
                        style="color: black">{{spec}}</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-link" ng-click="details(value)">
                            <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </b>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="{{$index+1}}-{{value.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                ---------------
                                ---------------
                                ---------------
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="val in value track by $index">
                                ----------------
                                ----------------
                                ----------------
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max-width` instead of `width` to get a maximum size of 1600px
and for smaller screens it gets to 100%

PS: or is there a min-width defined? Whats about other tables? Is the table-layout property really needed?

Answer (score 1):

Use percentage to specify width wherever you want